# How to Fake a Media Library Item and return an image from external provider instead

Tags: media-library

The scenario is the following:

For a single component we're getting the html content from an external provider. Including images. For each image we have to call a separate endpoint of the external provider. In return we get the Binary data with the http header "content-type:image/jpeg.

So basically I have this link `<img src="mydomain.com/-/city/images/test.jpg" />`

But this image does not exist and never will be in Sitecore. Instead for every image that starts with "-/city" I need to get the image from somewhere else.
My Idea was to overwrite the MediaProvider where I set the Url to an existing Media Item. Once that is assigned I want to call the endpoint and return the mediastream from my endpoint.
I've followed this blog post:
https://sitecorejumpstart.wordpress.com/2020/02/28/override-the-sitecore-media-provider/

But already failed here:

`public override MediaRequest ParseMediaRequest(HttpRequest request)`
as I cannot change the called Url to something else in the request.

Any idea how or if this is doable at all?
I'm using SC 9.1.1 btw with SxA

Comment: Maybe create a handler for `-/city/*` urls?

Comment: One scenario that I have done is with SharePoint documents. I created a new media template with a field containing details relevant to SharePoint such as the full URL and document name and so on. Then my rendering variant simply generates the URLs that I care about.

Comment: Agree with Marek here, I would avoid the Sitecore code and handle this yourself, esp since the prefix is not using the standard `-/media` prefix either.

Comment: Thank you! Will do so.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your question:

> every image that starts with `-/city` I need to get the image from somewhere else

In my opinion, if Sitecore has nothing to do with those urls, let's not even try to handle it by Sitecore. That's a waste of resources only.

Instead, create a handler for `-/city/*` urls and register it in `web.config`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<add verb="" path="-/city/*" type="My.Assembly.Namespace.CityMediaHandler, My.Assembly.Namespace" />
```

Potentially you will need to add `/-/city/` to `IgnoreUrlPrefixes`:

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/-/city/|/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|...
```